# How to show date from last monday to sunday?

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create an Analytics report and I want to set the date range from Monday to Sunday.

I am setting the Start date to: `=today()-7` and the End day to `=today()-1`, but this shows the last 7 days everytime I run the report (say I run it on wednesday, it will show data from wednesday to tuesday).

How can I set the date range so it shows it from last Monday to Sunday?

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Use [WEEKDAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092985?hl=en)

## Explanation

WEEKDAY returns the day of the week.

- To get the Monday's date, use this value to subtract it from today's date.
- To get the Sunday's date, add 6 to the monday date.

### Example

```
Today   =today()         11/14/2016
Weekday =WEEKDAY(B1,3)            0
Start   =B1-B2           11/14/2016
End     =B3+6            11/20/2016
```